# iOS : xcode 5.1.1 icons and launch images screen not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, icons, launching

I have set my app icons and launch images in Xcode in Project > Target > 'App Icons' And 'Launch Images'

The icons and screens are of the correct dimensions and I set them without using the asset catalog.

I have two problems:

1. If I set default Default-568h@2x.png and Default@2x.png launch images, Xcode builds my project for an iPhone 3.5 inch screen which puts the black strips at the top and bottom of my app on my iPhone 5.
2. The icons do not work at all.

I am using xcode 5.1.1 and have never had this issue before despite doing the 1 million times. 
Does anyone if this a bug or if there is a workaround ? Or must I sacrifice a small animal to the Apple gods in order to get this to work... If so please let me know which animal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you have to set all the image according to size of it

2) Press Use Asset catolog button just upper

3) it will ask you do you want to migrate icon or not you have to press migrate its done

Hope it will work.

Comment: Yes. It seems Xcode 5 doesn't really support doing it without the asset catalog.. although it seemingly allows it... I wonder if that's a bug. Thanks.

Comment: @Zigglzworth No, Xcode 5 supports both variants for managing images: with asset catalog and without it. You are free to choose any variant.

Comment: @Visput. Feel free to answer my question which addresses why I was unable to choose. Note that I have only observed issues in the latest version of Xcode (5.1.1)

Comment: @Zigglzworth I've already answered about hour ago. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your images attached to the target:

[image: Image settings]

I've tried to remove mark from checkbox for Default-568h@2x.png image target settings and saw black strips at the top and bottom after launching on device with 4" screen.